# How to make private Debian Repo

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, repository

I'm reading this [tutorial](http://linuxconfig.org/easy-way-to-create-a-debian-package-and-local-package-repository) for creating a local repo.

Now, I want to make my repo private, so only if you provide a username/password then should you be able to access the Debian package.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You configure your web server, FTP server, etc.—whatever you're using to share the repository with other machines—to require authentication.

The repository is just a bunch of files that your web server (typically) serves; there isn't really anything special about it. So you configure authentication the normal way for whichever web server you're using.

[Debian Administration](https://www.debian-administration.org/) has a [guide listing several methods](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/513/Restrict_Access_To_Your_Private_Debian_Repository).